# What field Django used in FOO_set?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am little bit comfused. Lets say I have such models.

**models.py**:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False)

class Game(models.Model):
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publishers = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
```

If I use next code:

```
current_company = Company.object.get(pk=1)
current_company.game_set.all()
```

as I understand it return all games of `current_company`, but what field (developer or publishers) Django used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But this code wouldn't be valid, for precisely this reason. If you tried to run it, Django would tell you that there was a conflict in the reverse relation.

If you have two relationships pointing to the same model, you need to explicitly set `related_name` on one of them to avoid this conflict.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! :) Can I ask you one more question? Is it possible to use different 'related_name' to both fields (developer, publishers)? Lets say something like: `related_name="games_developer"` to `developer` field and `related_name="games_publisher"` to `publishers` field?

Comment: Of course, you can use related_name on every field if you like.